# Neckties curling in the tip area

Tags: clothing

How do I un-curl the tip area of my necktie? Or, is there something I can sew onto tip area of necktie to keep it straight?

Answer (score 1):

You should try ironing your necktie. Choose the right setting on the iron for the material; in particular your iron should be relatively cool for silk. When ironing, use a “pressing cloth” to insulate the tie from the iron, preventing scorch marks and stains from transferring from the iron to the tie. You can purchase pressing cloths made from Teflon, e.g., or you can make your own from parchment paper (which you might have in your kitchen … now I never use a baking sheet without parchment) or muslin.  In a pinch you can use a pillowcase or sheet.

Iron the back of the tie first, checking frequently that the process doesn’t discolour the tie.

When the ironing is completed, try flattening the tie under books.

Comment: You can also use 1 or 2 layers of kitchen towel as an ironing cloth (either the disposeable paper towels or a clean cloth towel). Soak the towel in water and wring as much of the water out, then flatten the towel and lay it over the tie. The added water (steam) helps to increase the effect of the ironing without increasing the temperature. Press the iron directly down without moving it around to avoid pulling the fabric of the tie out of alignment.

Answer (score 1):

**Neckties *curling* in the *tip* area?**

Ironing is one method, I would recommend if used in conjunction with the use of some form of [*starch spray*](https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=starch%20spray%20for%20ironing&gclid=CjwKCAjwos-HBhB3EiwAe4xM9xLwGySEMyCGid_PEGiG6hyK1J_u3BrgPzKUeVcC4voMmHDFN2v1qhoC9ksQAvD_BwE&hvadid=324888061667&hvdev=t&hvlocphy=9001486&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=4653368292301322748&hvtargid=kwd-314782306260&hydadcr=23310_10308556&tag=googcana-20&ref=pd_sl_429w73gjye_e). It should stiffen the tip of your tie in place!

> Starching your clothes adds crispness and structure, providing body to cotton and linen items. It also creates a higher resistance to wrinkling and soiling. Using laundry starch will also ease ironing. Durable synthetics can be “starched,” but should not be be treated with grocery brand fabric starch spray.
>
> Starching has a long history, but it didn’t really become in vogue until the 16th century. Thanks to Elizabethan high society, the rise of lace and ruff collars, and the demand for professionally-laundered clothing starching clothes became a staple in the laundry routine. While starching linen and other fabrics has ancient roots, it had fallen out of practice until recently.
>
> Customers want to know: “can you starch rayon?” or “can you starch wool?” amongst other fabrics. To cut the confusion and to help you look more polished, we’ve put together the following guide. Discover how to keep wrinkles at bay longer, learn how starch acts as a stain-protective barrier, and much more.
>
> If you’re looking for the best fabric starch for ironing clothes, linens, and fabrics , you have a lot of options, including, Stiffen Up, a cornstarch, fresh-scented, non-aerosol spray that’s safe for cottons, linens, and even synthetic fabrics. The best part? You can save money on our ironing starch by only buying one spray with dual purposes.It is an excellent starch spray for clothes. - [Starching](https://www.thelaundress.com/how-to/360-wash/finishing/starching.html)

There are many brands on the market and you can even make your own!

[image: Brillo Basics 12 Oz. Aerosol Spray Starch]

[Brillo Basics 12 Oz. Aerosol Spray Starch](https://www.amazon.ca/Brillo-Basics-Aerosol-Spray-Starch/dp/B097V17GCY/ref=sr_1_4_sspa?dchild=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwos-HBhB3EiwAe4xM9xLwGySEMyCGid_PEGiG6hyK1J_u3BrgPzKUeVcC4voMmHDFN2v1qhoC9ksQAvD_BwE&hvadid=324888061667&hvdev=t&hvlocphy=9001486&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=4653368292301322748&hvtargid=kwd-314782306260&hydadcr=23310_10308556&keywords=starch%20spray%20for%20ironing&qid=1626660625&sr=8-4-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUE3N0lPSURPTlZFTUomZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTAwNDE5MzAxOUhXWkJRRTAyN1BaJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTAyODA4MjIzU1FYQzU2SExIOTRXJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==)